# Coffeescript and jQuery TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I recently had a little problem using a jquery  plugin with coffeescript (within the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline, if that helps). I looked around a bit, but couldn't really figure out, why it behaves this way.

So, why does this not work (talking about the corner call on $('.overlaybox')):

```
$ ->
  $('#slides').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))

  $(".overlaybox").corner()
```

but this does work (took the corners call out of the jQuery ready thing):

```
$ ->
  $('#slides').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))

$(".overlaybox").corner()
```

I keep getting a

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(".overlaybox").corner()')
```

if I leave it in there.. Maybe I'm just blind right now, but I can't figure out why I can't leave it in there. Even the compiled code looks legit (at least to me it does ;-)).

Thanks so much for your time and clarifying.

Marcel

**UPDATE**
Here's some relative code:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.Jcrop
//= require jquery.corner
//= require jqtextile
//= require_tree .

# app/assets/javascripts/slides.js
$ ->
  $(".overlaybox").draggable 
    containment: 'parent',
    drag: -> 
        offset = $(this).position()
        xPos = offset.left
        yPos = offset.top
        $('#slide_xpos').val(xPos)
        $('#slide_ypos').val(yPos)


  $('#slides').sortable
        axis: 'y'
    update: ->
        $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))

  $(".overlaybox").corner()
```

And then the view (app/views/slides/_form.html). The funny thing is, that corners works, as soon as I take it out of the jquery document ready event. 
I think I'm missing something substantial regarding the scope of all of this:
When I do a console.log inside the $ -> on corner, I get an undefined. But when I do the same outside of the $ -> (actually below), I get the proper output AND it gets fired even before the jquery (of course). But why is it not available in the jQuery block? Is it a scope thing with coffeescript I'm missing? (I'm having the same problem with a different plugin right now)

Thanks so much again!

**here's also the compiled javascript code, if that helps**

```
$(function() {
    console.log($('.overlaybox'));
    console.log($('.overlaybox').corner);
    $(".overlaybox").draggable({
      containment: 'parent',
      drag: function() {
        var offset, xPos, yPos;
        offset = $(this).position();
        xPos = offset.left;
        yPos = offset.top;
        $('#slide_xpos').val(xPos);
        return $('#slide_ypos').val(yPos);
      }
    });
    $('#slides').sortable({
      axis: 'y',
      update: function() {
        return $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'));
      }
    });
    return $(".overlaybox").corner();
  });
```

Comment: What does `sortable` have to do with this? Any chance of seeing a minimal case the reproduces the problem? The error indicates that the corner plugin isn't loaded when you try to use it, I would expect the first to have a better chance of working than the second.

Comment: Hey,
 I left the sortable code in there, to have at least some code inside the $ ->
I thought that might be clearer as I also mentioned what line I was talking about.

But yeah, according to my profiler, the corner plugin is definitely loaded before that coffeescript code up there. And to me the first example makes more sense too, but it just doesn't work.
Totally weird..

Comment: Can you look at `$.fn.corner` and see what's in there? Could there possibly be two things that want use the `corner` name?

Comment: Can you get out some relative code?

Comment: @island205 Sure, I added it to the coe above.

Comment: @muistooshort Yeah, I checked. Seems all good. there's not really much going on right now. It's just the [jquery corners plugin](https://github.com/malsup/corner). Again, I really think I'm missing something substantial here regarding the scope or so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was, that I had some precompiled assets (older stuff) in my rails public folder, that was kinda messing with my jQuery calls. Cleared it, learned my lessen, everything works now as expected.

**Anyway, thanks so much guys, I really appreciate your help!**

Comment: Sounds like something is messing with your jQuery `$` function. `$ ->` translates to `$(function() {...})` which is a variant of `$(document).ready(function() {...})` and that should be fine unless someone us taken over jQuery's `$`.

Comment: Oh my god.. I'm such a f***ing idiot! Thanks so much @muistooshort for this hint, that something's messing with my jQuery. Of course there was. I still had some precompiled assets from an earlier heroku deploy in my public folder.. Aaargh.. cleared it out, and everything is fine, and works like it supposed to be.. Damn!!

**Thanks again, I really appreciate your time!**

Comment: No worries, we're all idiots sometimes and the worst bugs to figure out are the ones that are staring you straight in the face.